# Populate multiple UIPickerview with one Array?

Tags: arrays, uipickerview

I have 4 UIpickerviews in one view. And I want to populate all of them with one array. At the moment, when the view appears it shows one picker view with the data, but the others are empty. When I start scrolling the second one, it starts to populate but the first one starts to get empty. I'm using the usual way of populating the UIPickerVIew.

Comment: Show some code, what data do you have in your array, and how do you propose to separate that single set into 4 sets, etc...???

Answer (score 0):

As a beginning of an answer to your question, you will have to implement the delegate routines for UIPickerViewDataSource.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 4;
}
```

You probably already have the above routine in your code!!!

Next you will have to implement the following:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch(component){
        case 0:
            // return X based upon how many for the left-most column
        case 1:
            // return X based upon how many for the second left-most column
        case 2:
            // return X based upon how many for the third left-most column
        default:  // Serves as 4
            // return X based upon how many for the right-most column        
    }
}
```

Or in the above routine it could simply (if your data to populate is n for each column thus your array size should be n * 4) be

```
[myArray count];  //  Where myArray is replaced with you array variable name
```

Lastly implement:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    // Assuming your array is filled with strings only
    int index = [myArray count] / 4 * component + row;
    return [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

This is assuming your array looks like

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

where the numbers represent which column the data belongs to, not the data itself